# Pantheon Files context menu (contract) to run script in terminal

Tags: release-loki, pantheon-files, contract

I would like to be able to have an option in the default file manager to run an executable file in terminal like I have in KDE/Dolphin.

This is useful in order to see the output (that could be temperature, countdown, etc...)

I know how to create contract files, but what I need is the line starting with `Exec=`, namely I need to know what terminal to use and with what arguments.

Comment: Can you point me at the documentation for contract files? I can't find it.

Comment: @MikeWild - I cannot, but I have found the answer for the default terminal.

Comment: Can you post it? The best I got was this: http://pastebin.com/mSEbZDuT. But I couldn't get it working.

Comment: @MikeWild - see below; the selected file has to be a proper executable script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gedit ~/.local/share/contractor/run_in_terminal.contract
```

with

```
[Contractor Entry]
Name=Run in terminal
Icon=terminal
MimeType=application/x-sh;application/x-executable;
Exec=pantheon-terminal -e %f
```

Not any file can be run like this, the selected file has to be a proper executable script.

Comment: What is the difference between `%U`, `%F`, and `%f`?

Comment: @MikeWild - I don't know much about it, I know `%f` is a single selected file name, `%u` is a URL that can be a path, the uppercase forms are usually multiple files or paths. But I don't really understand the subtle differences. I have found this: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#exec-variables - also: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqyjf.png

Comment: I can confirm that this works