# xterm crash - set pantheon-terminal to open terminal applications

Tags: pantheon-terminal

When I set *Emacs(terminal)* as my default editor and try to open a file, I get the error message

```
 Failed to execute child process "xterm" (No such file or directory)
```

Additionally, when I try to click on the *Emacs(terminal)* application, nothing happens (presumably because of the same error).

I know I can fix this by installing xterm (`sudo apt install xterm`). Ideally, however, I'd prefer to use the pantheon-terminal to do this. How can I trigger the elementary terminal when opening terminal applications?

Note:
I tried using the dconf editor. `org > gnome > desktop > applications > terminal`. But the value for exec, 'pantheon-terminal' seems like it should open the elementary terminal.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/10349) it should be:

```
io.elementary.terminal -e "emacs"
```

*answer updated for Juno & Hera*